# Readonly property in multiple texbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a Windows Form Application.

Well, C# programming is new to me and maybe this is a silly question, but how I can apply `ReadOnly` property in multiple textbox elements? I tried this code:

```
public void DoReadOnly(Control control){
   foreach (Control c in control.Controls){
      if (c.Controls != null && c.Controls.Count > 0){
         DoReadOnly(c);
      }
      else if (c is TextBox){
         (c as TextBox).ReadOnly = true;
      }
   }
}

public void getData(){
   DoReadOnly(this.Form);
}
```

The trouble is that I don't know which parameter I should put when I'm call doReadOnly's function. Visual Studio doesn't recognize `this.Form` like a valid argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call use this.

```
  DoReadOnly(this)
```

If the method is on Form class

Answer (score 0):

Pass only 'this', that object is your current form

```
public void getData(){
   DoReadOnly(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DoReadOnly(this);  instead of DoReadOnly(this.Form);

another thing, why getDate if you are going to put or change a propity, use setData